# Image path showing wrong when run from iis

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am new to mvc. I have created one web application in  [asp.net-mvc-2](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-2).

> src="../../images/1.jpg"

This is working when I debug from project but it is not loading from iis. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<img alt="Picture Display" src="<%= Url.Content("~/images/1.jpg")" />
```

this solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to use [UrlHelper.Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) Method, It converts a virtual (relative) path to an application absolute path.

Example

```
@Url.Content("~/images/1.jpg")
```

Here The `~` character matches the root of the site /.